# Subpackage in java

Tags: java

I have three programs in java.

```
//save on class ClassP1.java
package m1;
public class ClassP1{
    public void show1(){
        System.out.println("Welcome to package");
    }
}

//save on class ClassP2.java
package m1.m2;
public class ClassP2{
    public void show2(){
        System.out.println("Welcome 2 package");
    }
}

//save on class ClassP4.java
import m1.m2.*;
class ClassP4{  
  public static void main(String args[]){  
   System.out.println("subpackage");  
   ClassP2 p=new ClassP2();
   p.show2();

   m1.ClassP1 p1=new m1.ClassP1();
   p1.show1();
  }  
}
```

The last program ClassP4.java, is importing all classes in m1.m2. It has an error unless I edit line 5 as `m1.m2.ClassP2 p=new m1.m2.ClassP2();`
Why importing is not working?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please do not post code or (in your case) output as screenshots, but make them available in the post as text.

Comment: You may be importing all classes in package m1.m2, but you are not importing any classes from package m1

Comment: My program ClassP4.java on root directory, cannot access to ClassP2 that I imported to the ClassP4.java. This means it cannot access to the classes in m1.m2 folder. I have a solution: if I add a package command at the first line of ClassP4.java as "package m3;" it will work without any problem. But I don't want to add another package

Answer (score 1):

The `import m1.m2.*` ONLY imports classes in that direct package (in this case that's `ClassP2`) as your `ClassP1` is in a different package (m1).

In order to make this work you have 2 options:

1. Put `ClassP1` in the same package as 'ClassP2' and import that package with the wildcard (*) notation.
2. above `class ClassP4` in addition to `import m1.m2.*;` also add `import m1.*;`

Answer (score 1):

The packages define a structure within a Java program which is also reflected in the location of the source file (*.java) in the directory tree and once they are compiled also the class files.

Your `ClassP4` is in the default package as it does not have a `package` statement. Therefore this class is located at the root of your source tree. Then there is class `ClassP1` which is in package `m1` and therefore should be located in the subfolder `m1` relative to your default package. Similar with `ClassP2` which belongs to the package `m1.m2` and must be located in the directory `m1/m2` relative to the default package. This leaves you with the following structure:

```
 / ClassP4.java
 +- m1
    / ClassP1.java
    +- m2
    / ClassP2.java
```

Furthermore, in `ClassP4` you only import everything from the package `m1.m2` but nothing from `m1`.

Comment: My program ClassP4.java on root directory, cannot access to ClassP2 that I imported to the ClassP4.java. This means it cannot access to the classes in m1.m2 folder. I have a solution: if I add a package command at the first line of ClassP4.java as "package m3;" it will work without any problem. But I don't want to add another package.

Answer (score 0):

I think it will work if you use any of the below things :

1. add ClassP4 into m1 package
2. Use import m1.* in ClassP4 package;